# Use float to align div elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align some div tag containing some images for a small gallery. I used `float:right` and seems working but for some reason in some row instead of having a div the space is simply empty and the div is in the next row jumping to it. You can see it here : [example](http://dubai.salvatore-art.com/?genre=famosi#Galleria)

```
<div class='gridImage' >
    <div class='titel'>".$row['titel']."</div><br/>
    <img class='ritratti' data-size='". $row['size']. "' data-itemnr='". $row['itemNr']. "'  src='uploads/".$row['img']."'/><br/>
    <div>".$row['size']."</div><br/>
</div>";


.gridImage{

width:40%;
float:right;
padding:10px;
display:inline;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use an external stylesheet or `<style>` tag? all-inline CSS is bad practice and makes it harder for us to help you.

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not some third party site that will change or disappear tomorrow helping no one.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed now the post.

Comment: Can you please remove the downvote and close proposal for the post?

Comment: Don't use float for something like this is my suggestion, use columns instead.

Comment: Columns? You mean table?

Comment: You have three visible columns, so just use `divs` and then center the images inside of them, instead of trying to float them to the side on their own.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, can you write me an example, please?

Comment: This shows the rough idea, https://jsfiddle.net/hh4m6bw8/2/ , which is to make columns, and center the images in them, without using floats, which notoriously are a pain to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this?

```
.gridImage {
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```